# Joining a database to an Availability Group-error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting "Insufficient transaction log data" error when adding a database (42GB) to an availability group.
I have taken full and transaction log backups on the primary server and restored onto secondary, so I'm not sure why there is insufficient transaction logs.

I suspected that it was maybe due to the large amount of time it takes to transfer the backup files to the secondary server and by the time they restore on the secondary server, the log backup taken is insufficient.

Anyone have any suggestions why I'm getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try shrinking your log file before doing the restore. Also, allow the wizard to handle the Full backup, trans backup and restore.